# WSL with NVM SPFx 17.0.1

Tags: node.js, gulp, windows-subsystem-for-linux, spfx

I have a problem using version 1.17.1 with the WSL

1. I have my `nvm use` set to the current chain
2. I can `gulp clean` and `gulp build`

The problem is in the `gulp serve`, so give me this error in:

```bash
node_modules/opn/index.js:84:13)
```

```
if (opts.wait) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            cp.once('error', reject);

            cp.once('close', code => {
                if (code > 0) {
                    reject(new Error('Exited with code ' + code)); //HERE
                    return;
                }

                resolve(cp);
            });
        });
    }
```

Setup

```
/home/MyUser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib
├── @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.17.1
├── corepack@0.17.0
├── gulp-cli@2.3.0
├── npm@8.19.4
└── yo@4.3.1
```

Full Stack

```
15:58:00] 'serve' errored after 1.56 s
[15:58:00] Error: Exited with code 3
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/MyUser/Folder/Timex/node_modules/opn/index.js:84:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:552:15)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:458:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:552:15)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:301:12)
    at Pipe.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1
```

I'm wondering if it's from the node version, this is the actual `lts/gallium`, in the other hand I can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment) "Node.js v16 LTS (v16.13.x - v16.18.x, aka: Gallium)", this can be the problem, or I have here some other thing wrong?

If I use version 1.15.2 with `lts/fermium` i get the same error but wont stop, so I can see my webpart in the workbench

Answer (score 0):

Any luck on this error? I am seeing the same thing. This is on a brand new laptop, Win 11, WSL2, Ubuntu 22.04, nvm, spfx 1.17.1.

I deleted nvm and reinstalled the NodeJs environment, but same error.

Next step, delete and reinstall WSL.  Will reinstall Win11 if it gets that far.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is Node don't like the promise, it's not related to SPFX himself directly, no luck. But since node is the core of the chain Microsoft as 1st party should do anything, but unfortunately they close the tickets. Can be something related to WSL also but no one give feedback